# Enum constants for Pokemon Type

Tags: c++, enums

I'm making a simple, text-based Pokemon battle simulator using C++. So far I have a Pokemon class and a Pokemon move class, and each class has a member variable for type.

Right now I'm storing the types as strings - "fire", "water", "grass" etc. But I'm not sure if this is the best way to store the info, especially since I'll have to compare types for damage bonuses/penalties and that would mean having to parse entire strings instead of simple constants.

Would enums be a better choice? If so, do I just declare them the usual way at the beginning of the header file for one/both classes like this?

enum PKMN_type = {FIRE, WATER, GRASS, ... }

Will using enums instead of strings really have a measurable effect on programme efficiency in terms of size/memory?

Thanks.

Comment: If you use `enum`, you may want to provide functions that convert from text to `enum` and `enum` to text.  The C++ language does not provide facilities for converting `enum` to text.

Comment: Should these functions be helper functions for my move/Pokemon classes? Or should I make a separate enum class as suggested in the other answers?

Comment: I have been placing `enum`s into separate files along with conversion functions.  Yes, they help.  Although sometimes, I declare `enum`s in a class to promote encapsulation.

Answer (score 3):

Using `enum`s will have several benefits, including code speed, type safety, and making sure you detect it earlier if you accidentally try to make a steal-type Pokémon.

Since this is C++, I would usually recommend making it an `enum class` instead of just an `enum`. *However*, since Pokémon can have multiple types, you might like to do something have [something like `FLYING|NORMAL` to mean “both `FLYING` and `NORMAL`”](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BitmaskType), which you can do more easily with a plain `enum` than an `enum class`. You would accomplish this by setting each type to a different power of two:

```
enum pokemon_type {
    NORMAL = 1,
    FIRE = 2,
    FIGHTING = 4,
    WATER = 8,
    // ...
    // Depending on design, a `std::map` might be better, but you could do this:
    VULNERABLE_TO_FIRE = GRASS | ICE | BUG | STEEL,
    RESISTANT_TO_FIRE = FIRE | WATER | ROCK,
    IMMUNE_TO_FIRE = 0,  // Nothing is outright immune to fire
    // ...
};
```

In a less simple application I would recommend using an `enum class` anyway and implementing the relevant operators manually.

Comment: Is there a C++ library that I can use instead of making an enum class? I did some googling and std::map looks promising. But can it be used to map strings to ints and vice versa without the need to write text-to-int and int-to-text functions?

Comment: If you don’t want the bitfield, you can create it just like a regular `enum` but start it with `enum class` instead. If you do, [here](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/using-enum-classes-as-bitfields.html)’s an article about using `enum class` as a bitfield; you can either use read it or skip straight to the header file at the bottom. Neither `enum`s nor `enum class`es do the string conversion; you still need to do that yourself. The standard map classes are not bidirectional,  but why do you want to convert from strings to your enum values anyway?

Comment: Thank you. I need to output Pokemon types as strings but also compare an attack type with a Pokemon type for damage bonuses - for instance, fire attacks are super effective against grass Pokemon and will do more damage. Like you said in your answer, using a single character will have many benefits. That's why I want to convert from enums to strings and vice versa.

Comment: You need to output strings, but if you want to check if a Pokémon is vulnerable to a fire attack, you say `pokemon_type vulnerableToFire = pokemon_type::GRASS | pokemon_type::ICE | pokemon_type::BUG | pokemon_type::STEEL; if (defender.type & vulnerableToFire) { damage *= 2; }`. You could store the vulnerabilities, resistances, and immunities in `std::map`s, or even in the `enum class` itself (I’ve edited my answer to show that), but there’s no reason to convert to strings for that.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple, not-performance-critical program, comparing strings vs enums *probably* won't matter.
But, since enums can be just as expressive as strings for your purpose (and likely *will be* faster) I don't see any reason why not to use them.

Btw; generally prefer type-safe `enum class` over old-style `enum` in new code.